# Windows Service - UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: windows-services

I have a Windows Service created in .NET 4.

I need to access a file from antoher server and I get an exception:

`"UnauthorizedAccessException was caught" -  "Access to the path '(path)' is denied."`

If I make a new Windows Forms application which accessed that file, it works. The Windows Service runs as Local System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your machine account does not have permissions to access remote file share. You have to grant rights to the machine account `<DOMAIN>\<machine_name>$` on both file share level as well as file system level. For share permissions use `fsmgmt.msc`, for file system you can do it using `cacls` command.
Alternative solution is to impersonate a valid user account that already has permission to this directory.