# C# Windows Service (Network Service user) - UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, windows-services

We have hosted the windows service in Machine 1 as NetworkService account. When windows service tries to delete files from a shared folder in Machine 2, we are getting **UnauthorizedAccessException**. Shared Folder has given full permissions as NetworkService account. But if we are giving full permissions for **EveryOne** or **Users** for Shared folder, then everything goes well. We have tried setting the directory and file attributes to Normal. But still same exception is coming up.

> Machine1 and Machine 2 is in same domain. Logged in to both machine as
>   same user with admin privileges.

```
  SetDirAttributesNormal(new DirectoryInfo("//Machine2//SharedFolder"));

  private static void SetDirAttributesNormal(DirectoryInfo dir)
        {
            foreach (var subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
                SetDirAttributesNormal(subDir);
            foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                file.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
            }
        }
```

Comment: NetworkService is a local account - if you want this to work, you need to establish a AD trust between both machines ("I trust local users you authenticated"). It works for `EveryOne` because then it doesn't matter *where* the user authenticated. Probably the best solution is to use a domain account with tailored privileges.

Comment: "Shared Folder has given full permissions as NetworkService account." - not sure what you mean by that. If a service is running under the `NetworkService` account on Machine 1, that means it will present itself using Machine 1's *computer* account when access remote resources. So, did you give full permissions to `Machine 1` or did you accidentally grant permissions to *Machine 2*s `NetworkService` account?

Comment: See e.g. the [documentation on Network Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684272(v=vs.85).aspx): "A service that runs in the context of the NetworkService account presents the computer's credentials to remote servers. By default, the remote token contains SIDs for the Everyone and Authenticated Users groups. "

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I think I grant permissions to `Machine 2's NetworkService account`. Do I need to do as told here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047656/windows-service-unauthorizedaccessexception